# Is there a way to set the datasheet.aspx page so that certain groups see different fields?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions

datasheet.aspx is my standard view for a list rather than allitems.aspx.  The issue I need help with is setting the view so that the owners group can see the entire list, and the members group can only see select fields.  Is there a way to edit the .aspx page so that this can be accomplished?  I am using sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as column level security in SharePoint 2007 out of the box. In addition, datasheet view is not customizable.

I would recommend creating two separate views: one for members and one for owners. This really is security through obscurity though so I would not use it for any sensitive information.